# Static method and threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have put one question on MSDN forum but got two opposite answers. In general I am intersted how threading works with static classes. If my code calls this(below) static method from 10 threads at the same time, is it thread safe? I mean, how the code flows behind the scenes? Does every thread executes the code within itself (like I think it does with non-static classes) or it is different with static method and, because its static, all threads try to reach the code and collide? Thanks!

```
public static class A
{

    static void Method(object parameter)
    {
       SqlCeConnection = .....
    }
}
```

Link to MSDN question: [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/d37c6e9c-bb69-4985-9596-c071945a7dee?prof=required&ppud=4)

PS: I am sorry due to IE page errors I cannot click on "Add comment" or "Answer", Jon Skeet answer is good (as usually :)

Comment: please post the msdn forum link or let us know what were the answers

Comment: saw the link - I think they aren't two opposite answers. First one says 'It will run asynchronusly (at the same time)'. This is correct. But, your result will erroneous if there is no synchronization. Second one says, 'They will execute same code' (he just doesn't say at the same time asynchronously)

Answer (score 6):

It's exactly the same as with non-static classes. Being static doesn't affect anything really - except that static methods are generally *expected* to be thread-safe. They're not *automatically* thread-safe, but you should make sure that you implement them in a thread-safe manner.

If the code doesn't use any shared state, it should be fine. And yes, without any locking, all the threads can be executing the same method concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

A nice example can be singleton pattern.In this all you need is a single instance for a given class and that can be made sure by making the constructor private and giving a static method or property to access the instance.Following code snippets highlight the same :-

```
class MyClass
{
private MyClass()
{

}

public static MyClass Instance
{
    get
    {
        lock(typeof(MyClass))
        {
            if(__instance == null)
                __instance = new MyClass();
        }
        return __instance;
    }
}
```

}

Since the "Instance" method is marked static(thread consistent access) , but in multi threaded envoirnment you need to manully take care of it(using lock).